# How to Change the color of the text in the nav bar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I wanted to change the color of the text in my nav bar, to #b3b3b3 to be exact, but it looks like there are only the colours available that bootstrap gives me, how can I change this?

```
<nav class="navbar" style="color: #b3b3b3; background-color: #121212;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: try adding important: color: #b3b3b3 !important;

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of the text in the nav, you need to change the `<a>` tag's color, not the `<nav>` tag.

Try this:

```
<nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #121212;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: #b3b3b3">Navbar</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

or you can do this in style

```
nav a {
color: #b3b3b3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with css?

like

```
.custom-navbar {
    color: #b3b3b3;
}
```

Comment: That won't work because there's a rule in the bootstrap css file that overrides the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you've already got your answer, but here are some alternative ways you can do this in future:

1. Apply property directly to the class (or **id** if you want to use this property only once) in CSS file (perhaps the most useful way):

> ```
> .navbar-brand {
>   color: #b3b3b3;
> }
> ```

2. Apply property using **class names** and child combinator in CSS file:

> ```
> .navbar > .container-fluid > .navbar-brand  {
>   color: #b3b3b3;
> }
> ```

3. Apply property using **tags** and child combinator in CSS file:

> ```
> nav > div > a {
>  color: #b3b3b3;
> }
> ```

4. Applied an in-line style to the tag (not the best practice):

> ```
> <nav class="navbar" style="background-color: #121212;">
>  <div class="container-fluid">
>    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style='color: #b3b3b3;'>Navbar</a>
>  </div>
> </nav>
> ```